# split string and store in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I want to split the below mentioned string and save it in two seperate arraylist like state and city

```
 public class RoundValue {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String firstset = null;

        String city = "Tamilnadu;chennai-madurai-salem::Kerala;cochin-tiruvandrum-calicut";

        ArrayList<String> mState = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mCity = new ArrayList<String>();

        HashMap<String, List<String>> hashsplit = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> splitword1 = Arrays.asList(city.split("::"));

        if (splitword1.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < splitword1.size(); i++) {
                firstset = splitword1.get(i);


                List<String> firststate = Arrays.asList(firstset.split("-"));
                if (firststate.size() > 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < firststate.size(); j++) {
                        String firstcity = firststate.get(j);

                        List<String> secondcity = Arrays.asList(firstcity.split(";"));
                        if (secondcity.size() > 0) {
                            for (int k = 0; k < secondcity.size(); k++) {
                                String septcity = secondcity.get(k);
                                System.out.println("septcity Splitted:" + septcity);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have splitted each and every character, but i have to store state in seperate list and city in seperate list

Comment: What values should end up in the two Lists?

Comment: in one list state(Tamilnadu,kerala) and in another list cities(chennai,madurai,....)

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** Split your given string input as `Arrays.asList(city.split("::"));`, you alresy did it.

**Step 2:** Split each list in to array like, example `Tamilnadu;chennai-madurai-salem` using  `String both[]=string.split(";");` here you will get seperated state and cities.  like `both[0] is State`. both[1] is `chennai-madurai-salem`

**Step 3:** Split the cities string in both[1] usig `both[1].split("-")`

So Demo code I have given as below. You can modify.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String city = "Tamilnadu;chennai-madurai-salem::Kerala;cochin-tiruvandrum-calicut";
        ArrayList<String> mState = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> mCity = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> bothList= Arrays.asList(city.split("::"));

        for (String string : bothList) {
            String both[]=string.split(";");
            String state=both[0];
            List<String> tempCityList=Arrays.asList(both[1].split("-"));
            mState.add(state);
            mCity.addAll(tempCityList);
        }
        System.out.println("Your states");
        for (String string : mState) {
            System.out.print(string+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\nYour cities");
        for (String string : mCity) {
            System.out.print(string+" ");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Prasad on 6/17/2014.
 */
public class stack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="Tamilnadu;chennai-madurai-salem::Kerala;cochin-tiruvandrum-calicut";
        ArrayList<String> x1=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> x2=new ArrayList<String>();
        String string[]=s.split("::");
        for(String y:string){
            try{
                String[] temp=y.split(";");
                x1.add(temp[0]);
                x2.add(temp[1]);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        System.out.println(x1.toString());
        System.out.println(x2.toString());
    }

}
```